# derive eulers integration method from taylor series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I'm having a hard time understanding how to derive eulers integration method from tayler series expansion

I have an ODE and an initial value problem

$$
\dfrac{dy}{dt}=f(y,t) 
$$

$$
y(0)=y_{0}
$$

How does this taylor series expansion relate to eulers integration method

$$
y(t+h)=y(t)+hy'(t)+\frac{h^2}{2!}y''(t)+\frac{h^3}{3!}y'''....
$$

What exactly is h in this formula? is it that if i know y(0) i can find y(t+h)?

i was also given that if h is small i can write

$$
y(t+h)=y(t)+hy'(t)+\frac{h^2}{2!}y''(t)+\frac{h^3}{3!}y'''+O(h^4)
$$
Why is that? - i do know that it relates to the truncation error

And how do i come from this
$$
y(t+h)=y(t)+hy'(t)+\frac{h^2}{2!}y''(t)+\frac{h^3}{3!}y'''+O(h^4)
$$

to this

$$
y_{k+1}=y_{k}+h\cdot f(y_{k},t_{k})
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did almost everything! As you said,
$$
y(t+h) \approx y(t) + h y'(t),
$$

but, since $y(t)$ is the solution to $y'(t)=f(y,t)$, you can replace $y'(t)$ by $f(y(t),t)$ and obtain
$$
y(t+h) \approx y(t) + hf(y(t),t).
$$

If you prefer to use just integration, you can also start by obtaining an equivalent integral equation:
\begin{align*}
y'(t) = f(y(t),t) & \Rightarrow \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}} y'(t) dt = \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}}f(y(t),t) dt\\
&  \Leftrightarrow y(t_{k+1}) = y(t_k) + \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}}f(y(t),t) dt
\end{align*}

Now, if you use the rectangle rule,

$$
y(t_{k+1}) = y(t_k) + \int_{t_k}^{t_{k+1}}f(y(t),t) dt \approx y(t_k) + (t_{k+1}-t_k) f(y(t_k),t_k)
$$

you also obtain Euler's method.

Comment: Okay thank you, that helped! Just to clarify. $$
y(t+h)=y(t)+hy'(t)+\frac{h^2}{2!}y''(t)+\frac{h^3}{3!}y'''....
$$ 
This Taylor series expansions can find the next point ( + h ) from the initial value problem?

Comment: Yes, thats it. You "have" the solution at $t_k$ and you estimate the solution at $t_{k+1} = t_k+h$. In the case of Euler's method you discard all terms with powers $h^2$ or higher. In general, you start at $t_0$, where you have the initial value, and obtain a sequence of approximations of the solution at points $t_1, t_2, \cdots$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand.  - So, is it because we truncate all terms with power of h^2 away that eulers is a 1st order integration method?

Comment: Yes. In fact, since we only have the correct value at $t_0$, we accumulate errors as we move on in time and, in the end, the global error is in fact $O(h)$.

Comment: Yes i understand all that. It was actually just how we got from a initial value problem and taylor series expansion to eulers integration method.

Comment: I added another approach to my answer, in case you prefer not to use Taylor's approximation explictly.

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot! Is it correct to say that we truncate away some terms, because we can't calculate taylor series infinity, and therefore we accept the truncation error.